# Rails hstore and accepts_nested_attributes_for with has_many relation don't stores nested object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, has-many, rails-postgresql, hstore

Rails don't want store changed attributes of nested object. I use:

- Rails 4
- Postgresql 9.3
- Hstore column in Postgresql
- Nested attributes in views
- Using with rolify gem

Here the database table:

```
create_table :accounts_roles do |t|
  t.references :account, null: false
  t.references :role,    null: false
  t.hstore     :configurations
  t.timestamps
end
```

Here the models:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :accounts_roles
  has_many :roles, through: :accounts_roles

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :accounts_roles
end

class AccountsRole < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :role

  store_accessor :configurations, :color
end
```

The controller permits all attributes for debug:

```
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit!
end
```

In my view I use fields_for:

```
<%= form_for @account ... %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :accounts_roles do |ar| %>
    <%= ar.text_field :color ... %>
```

If I submit the edit form the parameter hash looks fine:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "account"=>{..., "accounts_roles_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"color"=>"green", "id"=>"5"}}},...}
```

**But the color don't changes to "green", it is still "red"!**

In the rails console I have try out to do the same process manually:

```
> u = Account.first
> u.account_roles.first.color
 => "red"
> u.update(accounts_roles_attributes: { color: "green", id: 5 } )
 => true
> u.account_roles.first.color
 => "green"
> u.save
 => true
> u = Account.first
> u.account_roles.first.color
 => "red"
```

**But without success. The attribute color remains "red".**
**Any idea?**

Comment: not permitted param? https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: did you try restarting your server/console? also, try using bang methods: save!, update! while trying to debug this. Although update/save return true, check wether record is .changed? and/or  .persisted? after those. You could also check postgresql logs to check specific transactions.

Comment: Yes, I have restart server and console many times. I cannot see a SQL statement in the log that updates the `accounts_roles` table! Is like, rails don't see that the submitted attribute is not the same as in the database.

Comment: not sure wether that might be the case but, .update could return true as user object actually gets updated - that might not be the case for nested objects? after update when you ask for `u.account_roles.first.color` you arent hitting the database - youre getting the property of the object you just set.

Comment: After `u.save` in this example (see console example), I reload the object with `u = Account.first` to see if the database has the update. If I do: `ar = u.account_roles.first`and then `ar.color = 'green'` and `ar.save` then I see the update SQL transition. This works. So, it is not a validation problem. Because it works in this way. But why don't works in the view with nested attributes?

Comment: `t.references :role,    null: false` tells the db not to accept null values, might it be the case that you got an invalid record in your db arleady (lacks :role_id)? Youre trying to update the color on an invalid record (and youre not passing :role_id in your request either) so nothing persists in the database?

Comment: I have removed all restrictions: validations, database null etc. but it don't work. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70887/discussion-between-mymlyn-and-phlegx).

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem! I use rolify gem on model account. I have decided to change the defined rolify association `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` to a `has_many :accounts_roles` and `has_many :roles, through: :accounts_roles`. This had raised the issue because the gem defines the association by itself inside the gem. So, the model had both associations defined, `has_and_belongs_to_many :roles` and `has_many through`. A hook solves the problem (remove association `has_many :accounts_roles` and `has_many :roles, through: :accounts_roles` from model account).

```
# config/initializers/hook_rolify.rb
module Rolify
  def rolify(options = {})
    include Role
    extend Dynamic if Rolify.dynamic_shortcuts

    options.reverse_merge!({:role_cname => 'Role'})
    self.role_cname = options[:role_cname]
    self.role_table_name = self.role_cname.tableize.gsub(/\//, "_")

    default_join_table = "#{self.to_s.tableize.gsub(/\//, "_")}_#{self.role_table_name}"
    options.reverse_merge!({:role_join_table_name => default_join_table})
    self.role_join_table_name = options[:role_join_table_name]

    rolify_options = { :class_name => options[:role_cname].camelize }
    # NOTE not needed any more
    # rolify_options.merge!({ :join_table => self.role_join_table_name }) if Rolify.orm == "active_record"
    rolify_options.merge!(options.reject{ |k,v| ![ :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove ].include? k.to_sym })

    # NOTE defining the association has_many through
    # has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, rolify_options
    has_many self.role_join_table_name.to_sym
    has_many :roles, rolify_options.merge!(through: self.role_join_table_name.to_sym)

    self.adapter = Rolify::Adapter::Base.create("role_adapter",  self.role_cname, self.name)
    load_dynamic_methods if Rolify.dynamic_shortcuts
  end
end
```